# How to replace space as a newline in a textBox with Multiline property set to true?

Tags: c#, winforms

Suppose I have this string:

```
string str = "The quick brown fox     jumps over the lazy dog";
```

How can I replace or ignore the spaces in the string and enter each word in the multiline textBox?

Expected output:

```
The  
quick    
brown  
fox  
jumps  
over  
the   
lazy   
dog
```

My .NET framework version is 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
textBox.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, str.Split(new char[] {' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

UPDATE: Of course, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries should be used.

UPDATE2: alternative version via regular expression

```
textBox.Text = Regex.Replace(str, @"\s+", Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: Good, except it won't ignore the empty elements of the Split. You're missing `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`

Comment: close, but not the best answer, it will add empty rows for the 4 or so spaces after each other.

Comment: @Mr.DDD, in this case empty lines will be added

Comment: because my comment was written before your edit. And by then you didn't use the `StringSplitOptions` :)

Answer (score 4):

```
mytextbox.Text=String.Join(Environment.NewLine,str.Split(new[]{' '},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

Would be my guess, if I understand the question correctly.

Comment: I would use `Environment.NewLine` instead of your `"\r\n"`

Comment: absolutely! `Environment.NewLine` has been with us since .Net 1.1  :D  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline%28v=VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: @Bazz: Was pressed for horizontal real estate, heh, but good mention. - @yonan226: Yes, String functions are pretty primitive. ;-)

Comment: In Framework 2.0 it will not compile.
1) there is no Split method with char 2) there is no extension method Join

Comment: Arg, been in 4.0 land (and so is my MSDN!) ;p Fixed, my apologies.

Comment: @Bazzz: I also often wonder why .NET needs such a thing as `Environment.NewLine` if they don't have version of *nix. It must be to eat up my carpel tunnel... ;p

Comment: Now it looks exactly as mine :)

Comment: @Brad Christie 1) hard-coded NewLine string is not good 2) They always thinking about going to *nix)

Comment: yeah, the error is `error: ; expected`  here's the code `txtTextField.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine,str.Split(new[]{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));`

Comment: @yonan2236: maybe short-hand arrays aren't allowed in 2? Try `new char[]{' '}`

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "The quick brown fox     jumps over the lazy dog";
string[] splits = str.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "The quick brown fox     jumps over the lazy dog";
string[] ab = str.Split(' ');
if (ab != null && ab.Length > 0)
{
    string de = ab[0].Trim();
    for (int i = 1; i < ab.Length; i++)
    {
        de += "\n" + ab[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want compact and simple this may be the best bet:

```
Textbox.Lines = MyString.Split(' ');
```

If you're wanting to split the text already in the box this may work:

```
Textbox.Lines = Textbox.Text.Split(' ');
```